# Creating a random redirect button

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect

I have the following code, which I want to use with a large, center-aligned button to redirect visitors to a website to one of an array of URLs at random:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Create an array of the links to choose from:
var links = new Array();
links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
links[1] = "http://www.bing.com/";
links[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";

function openLink() {
  // Chooses a random link:
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
  parent.location = links[i];
  return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="openLink();">
</body>
</html>
```

How should I adapt the above code to achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be window.location.replace("url") or window.location = "url"

Comment: `window.location.href` not just `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

let links = []; // don't use new Array() anymore
links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
links[1] = "http://www.bing.com/";
links[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";
function openLink() {
  var i = ~~(Math.random() * links.length);
  window.location.href = links[i]; // if must be 'parent' leave as 'parent'
  return false;
}
openLink(); // you can also possibly use window.onload = openLink();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Snippet doesn't work quite as well as it should. Try putting this in a test environment. I opened a blank tab and did a test using Inspect Element's console and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try To this code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Create an array of the links to choose from:
var links = new Array();
links[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
links[1] = "http://www.bing.com/";
links[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";

function openLink() {
  // Chooses a random link:
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
  parent.location = links[i];
  return false;
}
//-->
</script>
<style>
.btn {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background:#125288;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<center>
<button onclick="openLink();" class='btn'>Try to Click</button>
</center>
</html>
```